# Access file on google drive using Python Script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Please can anyone help me with how to fetch file stored in google drive?
I've a VM Compute engine in GCP and associated service account. This service account have an access to the google drive folder.

I thought to use python script on VM while will access the File on GDrive.
Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try to [impersonate the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) you are using.

[Attaching a service account to a resource](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-to-resources)

For some Google Cloud resources, you can specify a user-managed service account that the resource uses as its default identity. This process is known as attaching the service account to the resource, or associating the service account with the resource.

When a resource needs to access other Google Cloud services and resources, it impersonates the service account that is attached to itself. For example, if you attach a service account to a Compute Engine instance, and the applications on the instance use a client library to call Google Cloud APIs, those applications automatically impersonate the attached service account.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: So in this case I've to create a compute engine with a default service account? This service account will automatically access the drive's data without asking for consent?